# Lenovo M92P tiny PC Graphics Card Upgrade

Tags: graphics-card, gpu, form-factor, lenovo-desktop-computer

Is it possible or does any tried upgrading the the graphics card of Lenovo M92P Tiny(1 Litre)? Here is the specs: http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/desktops/thinkcentre/m-series-tiny/m92p/

I'm planning to buy an external graphics card dock/adapter: http://www.ebay.com/itm/V8-0-EXP-GDC-Beast-Laptop-Exter...

Any suggestions?

Thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most eGPU adapters utilize PCI-e (your model uses an expresscard output but your pc doesn't have the corresponding slot which means you need to go for a PCI-e model) to connect to your PC. You need to check and verify that you have a spare PCI-e slot on your mainboard and adapter you'll buy supports the corresponding PCI-e protocol. I can't recommend a particular brand here but you should look for alternative versions of that adapter.

[M92P Tiny Review And Specs](http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2012/08/review-ivy-bridge-brings-big-performance-to-tiny-lenovo-thinkcentre-m92p/2/)

Comment: My board has only one mPCIe slot, I think it is used for wlan. 

Please see this link http://www.d9commerce.com/api-connect/image_store/20140908/7851-6243-20140908-3340.jpg

Comment: In that case you'll need to give up on wifi function in favor of eGPU. :) (same is true for most of laptop users.)

Comment: At least the internal WiFi.  Slow wireless works fine over and USB plug, though it would be nice if you could reuse the integrated antennas.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I think i will give a try. 

One more thing that worries me is the "wireless card whitelist issue". I've heard a lot of problems about it though others managed to do some work around.

Has anyone of you encountered that problem? Any advice?